# How to set dataLabel Format and axis label angle in R highcharter package

Tags: r, highcharts

I am experimenting with R highcharter package to create a bar chart function. the code is as below. I request help in 
1-How to change the format of the dataLabels to percentage ? 
2-How to set X-axis label display angle. I want to set it to 45 degrees

```
hcbar_categorycount_vertical <- function(data=x,var=y){
df <- data.frame(prop.table(table(data[var])))
names(df) <- c(var,'Proportion')
df$Proportion <- round(df$Proportion*100,2)
df <- df%>% arrange(-Proportion)
df[,1] <- as.character(df[,1])
df[,1] <- factor(df[,1], levels = df[,1])
df$Cumulative <- round(cumsum(df$Proportion),2)

highchart(debug = TRUE) %>%
hc_xAxis(categories=df[[1]]) %>%
hc_yAxis(labels = list(format = "{value}%"), max = 100) %>%
hc_add_series(name=var,data=df$Proportion,type = "column",dataLabels =       list(enabled = TRUE, format='{point.label}%'))
}
```

I am not sure what should be the syntax of "format" within dataLabel property list.The above code does not seem to work. I already referred to the highcharter vignette and this site : http://jkunst.com/highcharter/highcharts-api.html#hc_xaxis-and-hc_yaxis

But could not find an answer. Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

@jeganathan-velu,

1) Try changing the `'{point.label}%'`by `'{point.y}%'`

2) See the highcharts [example](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-rotated-labels/grid). You need to add to the `hc_xAxis` the argument `labels = list(rotation = 90)`

highcharter package is just the wrapper of highcharts so you can check *all* the examples and the well documented API from highcharts. [Replicating highcharts demos](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/highcharter/vignettes/replicating-highcharts-demos.html)

Comment: Thanks @jbkunst for the solution.And many thanks for a great R package!

Comment: @jeganathan-velu And thanks to you for try the package!

Answer (score 5):

Found the answer after trial and error and some further research in http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.labels.rotation

Posting the updated code component for the benefit of others.

```
hc_xAxis(categories=df[[1]],labels = list(rotation=-45)) %>%
hc_yAxis(labels = list(format = "{value}%"), max = 100) %>%
hc_add_series(name=var,data=df$Proportion,type = "column",dataLabels = list(enabled = TRUE, format='{point.y}%'))
```

Comment: Nice, I just see your answer ;)!